# German TTS for kindle PC

Tags: kindle, text-to-speech

Is it possible to listen an ebook with another language then english ?
If yes, how can I switch to german for example ?

Comment: no suggestions ?

Answer (score -1):

The German Amazon (***Amazon.de***) is a good source for (German) Kindle audio books.  Die website wird *www.amazon.de*, dann verwenden Sie den Suchbegriff (auf Deutsch) "*Kindle-Shop*" --> "*hörbücher kindle*".

Ich hoffe, dies wird Ihnen helfen -- wenn du einen Kindle hast!